# Making a CardView clickable to load an activity with the same firebase data

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, cardview

i'm facing a small issue figuring out on the following -
I have a RecyclerView in my MainActivity, the RecyclerView has CardView within it.
The data displays on the MinActivity page, cuz the RecyclerView is in it.

Now, I want a new activity to pop-up once a CardView is clicked.
The new activity will use the same data as the CardView had.
I'm using Firebase storage if it matters.

Example - 
My CardView 1 has a name, age and country - Jake, 19, UK.
The other activity will get the collection data from Firebase which is the exact same as CardView 1 and implement it in to the new activity.

I hope I explained it well..

(I'm using getters and setters)

My code so far (Only the needed parts)-

**MainActivity**

```
list_post = new ArrayList<>();
list_header = new ArrayList<>();

postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(list_post);
headerAdapter = new HeaderAdapter(list_header);


headerRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.headerRecycler);
headerRecycler.setAdapter(headerAdapter);
headerRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
firebaseFirestore.collection("FeaturedPosts").limit(1).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshotss, FirebaseFirestoreException ee) {

        for (DocumentChange doc2: queryDocumentSnapshotss.getDocumentChanges()) {
            if (doc2.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                ListForHeader listForHeader = doc2.getDocument().toObject(ListForHeader.class);
                list_header.add(listForHeader);
                headerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class HeaderAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeaderAdapter.ViewHolder2> {


public List<ListForHeader> list_header;

public Context contextt;

public HeaderAdapter (List<ListForHeader> list_header) {

    this.list_header = list_header;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public HeaderAdapter.ViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.featured_activity, parent, false);
    contextt = parent.getContext();

    return new HeaderAdapter.ViewHolder2(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HeaderAdapter.ViewHolder2 holder, int position) {

    String header_data2 = list_header.get(position).getHeader2();
    holder.setHeaderText2(header_data2);

    String date_data2 = list_header.get(position).getDate2();
    holder.setDateText2(date_data2);

    String image_data2 = list_header.get(position).getImage_url2();
    holder.setIntroIMG2(image_data2);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list_header.size();
}

public class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View mView;

    private ImageView introIMG2;
    private TextView headerText2;
    private TextView dateText2;


    public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setHeaderText2(String headText2) {

        headerText2 = mView.findViewById(R.id.introHeader2);
        headerText2.setText(headText2);

    }

    public void setDateText2(String tarihText2) {

        dateText2 = mView.findViewById(R.id.introDate2);
        dateText2.setText(tarihText2);

    }

    public void setIntroIMG2 (String downloadUri) {

        introIMG2 = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.introImage2);
        Glide.with(contextt).load(downloadUri).into(introIMG2);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see its simple issue. You can add cardview Id to viewHolder and set onlclicklister to it in bindview and in on click Start activity and pass the current data in Intent. Let me know if its something else stopping you from sending data or getting click on cardview. 
Extra: you may have to set cardview clickable true.

here is the example.

```
   class DemoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
   View.OnClickListener {   

    @BindView(R.id.card)
    CardView cardView;


    public DemoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.card:
                doSomethingOn(mList.get(getAdapterPosition()))
                break;
        }
    }

  public class BookingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
Context mContext;
ArrayList<Booking> mList;
public BookingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Booking> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mList = list;
    this.cancelBookingListener = cancelBookingListener;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, can you give me some example? Sadly I didn't understand how you want me to do it.

Comment: Hope it helps or you can just in BindviewHolder can do like demoViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickLister(new OnClickListener().....

Comment: That's great, now if I want to get the key / id (idk what's the difference) and use it as a String.. how can I do that?

Comment: I mean, I want a new activity to be opened on a cardView click, then on the new activity im going to get the key from the cardView post and use it to find the exact value of the child i need, so I could change a TextView to the exact value inside the child of a clicked cardview key.. Hope you understood me.

Comment: Key or Id of what? What do you want to achieve from that